# Display current value of item in the form input field

Tags: php, html, forms

I am looking to display the current value of the `NumberedEntered` value in the input box.

Currently it will only display the current value when I click submit then refresh. Does anyone know how I can echo it back as soon as I click submit?
Thanks.

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>
  <tr>
    <form action "index.php" method "post" name='form1'>
      <td align="center" width="40%" ><?php echo $user['FullName']; ?><input type="hidden" Name="FullName" value="<?php echo $user['FullName']; ?>" /></td>
      <td width="30%"><input type="number" name="NumberedEntered" value="<?php echo $user['NumberedEntered']; ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "as soon as I click submit"?  Do you not want the page to refresh at all?  If that's the case you'd need to use JavaScript to modify the page without reloading it.  If you need some server-side calculation to be performed then you'd need to use AJAX, but if all you want to do is display the value then you can do that with just JavaScript and not PHP is needed at all.

Comment: I am sending the NumberedEntered value to a database. I just want the input box to keep that current value that was just submitted without having to click refresh.

Comment: When I try and input the POST value it posts the submitted value in every users NumberedEntered input field instead of what I'm after and just doing it for the selected user. `<td width="30%"><input type="number" name="NumberedEntered" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['NumberedEntered'])) {echo htmlentities($_POST['NumberedEntered']); }?>" /></td>`

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts?